# C++ How does order of instance creation matter?

Tags: c++, class, instance, creation

I have a class that creates instances of other classes, and when I call them, compiler gives me warning about order of the instances. Why does it matter? It does same job, regardless of the order.

E.g. I have this in my core class header file (core class handles game loop):

```
HUD hud;
World myWorld;
```

Like this they do all they need to. But compiler gives a warning:

```
'Core::myWorld' will be initialized after [-Wreorder]|
```

Then if I put myWorld instance above the hud instance, it doesn't give me warning anymore. I was just wondering, how on earth does it matter which order they are in?

Comment: Can't tell without knowing what `HUD` and `World` are. Does HUD refer to something in World?

Comment: Can you post more information on this, like your constructor(s)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Warning is since, in constructor initializer-list you initialize `World` before `HUD`, but actually members will be initialized in order they are declared in class.

Just litle example, where it can be worse:

```
class B
{
public:
   B(int i) : value(i) {}
private:
   int value;
};

class A
{
public:
   A() : value(10), b(value)
   {
   }
private:
   B b;
   int value;
};
```

Here `b` will be initialized before `value` and so, something will be sended to `b` constructor, but not `10` as programmer want.

Comment: I think the question is why this matters. Which you now answered with an example :-)

Answer (score 0):

With

```
struct C
{
    C() : p(std::make_unique<int>(42)), j(*p) {} // initialization doesn't use this order.

    // but the order here:
    int j;
    std::unique_ptr<int> p;
};
```

you will dereference `nullptr` as `j` is initialized before `p`.